# Regex for all strings not containing a specific string

Tags: php, regex

I need to choose the original image in my example is a 'image1.jpg' with any extension.

```
image1-150x150.jpg
image1-225x300.jpg
image1-768x1024.jpg
image1.jpg
```

I've tried the following:

```
preg_grep("/-([0-9]+x[0-9])+/", $image);
```

How do I exclude other files and select "image1.jpg"?

Comment: Could you add a little context please?

Comment: thanks. it's works, but I wanted to write without PREG_GREP_INVERT. because it will be used in some cases without preg_grep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wanted to write without `PREG_GREP_INVERT`, because it will be used in some cases without `preg_grep`

Then you could use a negative lookahead to negate strings that contain the pattern `\d+x\d+`:

```
/^((?:.(?!\d+x\d+))*\.[^.]+)$/gm
```

It would capture `image1.jpg` based on the input you provided - [example here](https://regex101.com/r/tM2bR8/1).

- `^` - Anchor to match the beginning of the line (since the `m` flag is used).
- `.(?!\d+x\d+))*` - Match zero or more characters not followed by `\d+x\d+`
- `\.[^.]+` - Match the `.` character literally followed by one or more characters that are not `.`
- `$` - Anchor to match the end of the line.

Comment: It works. Thanks for the detailed description.Thanks to all who responded. Happy New Year